# Magpie removes angle brackets from RSS feed

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, magpie

I've found two WP installs on different servers, same WP version. Magpie returns different RSS content from same feed, one of the blogs returns the contents with angle brackets removed.

The XML is retrieved exactly the same for both blogs, the difference comes after calling `Magpie($rss_content)`.

Here's the XML PHP config from both servers:

```
XML Support             active
XML Namespace Support   active

EXPAT Version           expat_1.95.7

libxml2 Version      2.7.3  <-- This one fails
```

Anyone knows what's causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to RSS, and not directy to Magpie, but possibly related?: [Problems With libxml2 For WordPress XML-RPC Users](http://josephscott.org/archives/2008/12/problems-with-libxml2-for-wordpress-xml-rpc-users/)